# Save/restore thread local storage

Tags: freepascal, seh, thread-local-storage, fiber

I'm trying to use [w32 fiber API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682661%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in FreePascal to implement coroutine class. So far I could allocate worker context (CreateFiber) and switch between contexts (SwitchToFiber).

However I couldn't get exceptions working reliably. There should be different exception chains in different contexts. When using w32 SEH exception handler chain, chain switching happens automatically in SwitchToFiber. But FreePascal doesn't use w32 SEH chain and rather stores its' own chain in threadvar.

I'd like to go ahead and try to save/restore threadvars by hand. So far I could get ThreadEnvironmentBlock structure:

```
function GetCurrentTEB: PThreadEnvironmentBlock;
asm
  mov eax, fs:[$18]
end;
```

I believe threadvars are stored in ThreadLocalStorage which is somewhere inside ThreadEnvironmentBlock ;-) Now I'd like to properly save and restore the ThreadLocalStorage.
The following information is needed:

1. Where in ThreadEnvironmentBlock threadvars are stored?
2. How to save/store them into/from global heap?